# reset chart to 0 in grafan

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Below is a chart I have in grafana:

[image]

My problem is that if my chosen time range is say 5 minutes, the graph wont show only what happened in the last 5 minutes. So in the picture, nothing happened in the past 5 minutes so it's just showing the last points it has. How can I change this so that it goes back to zero if nothing has changed? I'm using a Prometheus counter for this, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the Prometheus documentation, a counter value in itself is not of much use. It depends on when your job was last restarted and everything that happened since.

What's interesting about a counter is how much it changed over some period of time. I.e. either the average rate of change per second (e.g. 3 queries per second) or the increase over some time range (e.g. 10K queries in the last hour).

So instead of graphing something like e.g. `http_requests`, you should graph `rate(http_requests[1m])` (the averate number of requests over the previous 1 minute) or `increase(http_requests[1h])` (the total number of requests over the past hour). You can play with the range size until you get something which makes sense for your data. But make sure to use a range at least 2x your scrape interval (and ideally more, as Prometheus is somewhat daft in the way it computes rates/increases).

Comment: Whats the point of the time range button in grafana if I'm going to override it with my queries?

Comment: The rate/increase will be computed for 1 minute/hour back from each point in the range. E.g. (in the case of the graph you posted) you'll get the rate over the 1 minute before 16:39:30, the rate over the 1 minute before 16:40:00, the rate over the one minute before 16:40:30 and so on. Try it side by side with your current graph and you'll understand.